# SQLite blob data types

Tags: c++, sqlite

I started using SQLite database in my C++ application. I have a query about the blob data type. I have a project specific structure local structure. I am binding my structure object and doing an insert.

1. what is the scope of the object now?
2. if I restart my project and read from database whether that object still exists?
3. if I want to update the data with the new structure, should I first delete the old one and again do bind?

Comment: Try and check yourself :)

Comment: @janisz any other suggestions?

Comment: i just started using sqlite only from 2-3 days.Am not getting anything regarding the blob scopes anywhere.Any little help is appreciated

Comment: For question 1 2 and 3 with the information you supply the answer is the same: "it depends!"...    I suggest that you ask one question at a time and you add some code all the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is out of the scope of your program by definition as it is stored in the database which is external to your program.

Once you read it back from the database the *variable you read it into* is now in the scope of your C++ program depending on how you defined the variable (static, automatic etc.).